# For this switch statement, why does the 'case' inside a 'default' get executed even when the case doesn't match?

Tags: java

For this `switch` statement, why does the '`case`' inside a '`default`' get executed even when there is no match?
(from Java Certification by Boyarsky-Selikoff OCP-17)

I expected a *compiler error*. I don't understand how you can have a case statement inside a default statement.

I did not know that `default` is just another special type of `case` label and is treated similarly. I thought that default was a keyword reserved for all other values. I am surprised to find that the case matching stops even though there is a `case 44:`. So the `default` overrides the `case`?

Actual:

```
5 2 1
```

---

```
static void f11(){
    var tailFeathers = 3;
    final var one = 1;
    switch (tailFeathers) {
        case one: System.out.print(3 + " ");
        default:
            case 44: System.out.print(5 + " ");
    }
```

Comment: @user16320675 I mean, why _wouldn't_ you expect one, lots of compilers for lots of languages throw errors on undeclared fall throughs, C# has `Control cannot fall through from one case label to another` for example, and in C++ you can use `[[fallthrough]];` to make it explicit that fall through is intended. If for example OP was coming from another language, they have every reason to expect it to throw an error.

Comment: The compiler doesn't look at how much indentation you put on each line (like python, for example), so it sees that last `case` as AFTER the `default` block, not INSIDE it.  And there's no rule that says that `default` has to be the last branch.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I did not know that `default` is just another special type of `case` label and is treated similarly. I thought that `default` was a keyword reserved for all other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `switch` case statements "fall-through". You need a `break`.

```
switch (tailFeathers) {
    case one:
        System.out.print(3 + " ");
        break; // One would fall through to default
    default:
        break; // Default would fall through to 44
    case 44: System.out.print(5 + " "); // last statement
}
```

Case matching is traditionally implemented as a type of jump table, and the jump happens once. The value being examined is `tailFeathers` (`3`). `3` is not `44` and `3` is not `1`. The only matching label is `default`. So it jumps to the `default` label. Which is empty. If it has a `break` the `switch` ends. Without a `break` it falls through to the next `case` (if any), otherwise the `switch` ends. In no case does case matching continue.

Not legal in Java, in C this behavior was used to implement [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) (for loop unrolling). The kind of hack your elders warned you about.

Comment: No, please remove the 'break'. I don't understand how you can have a case statement inside a default statement.

Comment: You don't. `default` is a kind of `case` statement. It's the no-match `case` statement. It can appear in any order. And indentation is not significant.

Comment: but then after the default there is a case keyword. I would expect a compiler error.

Comment: case statements can appear in any order. `default` can be first. `default` can be last. `default` can be in the middle. Your expectations were incorrect.

Comment: @likejudo The `case 44:` statement is _not **"inside"**_ the default statement. Just because you indented it in your originally posted code, that doesn't make it "inside", you would need braces `{}` to create a block. Your "default:" and "case 44:" are just two case labels on the _same_ statement block, a block consisting of a single statement – `System.out.print(5 + " ");`

Comment: I did not know that `default` is just another special type of `case` label and is treated similarly. I thought that `default` was a keyword reserved for all other values.

Comment: I am surprised to find that the case matching stops even though there is a `case 44:`

Comment: Is that a new question? The case matching stops because the case matching is a type of jump table and the jump happens **once**. The value being examined is `tailFeathers` (`3`). `3` is not `44`. So why would the case matching consider `case 44`? The only matching label is `default`. So it jumps to the `default` label. Which is empty. If it has a `break` the `switch` ends. Without a `break` it *falls through* to the next case (if any), otherwise the `switch` ends. In no case does case matching continue.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you please copy-paste your last comment into the answer? It explains it finally, for me. I shall accept your answer - thanks,

Answer (score 3):

If you would format that code (formatting doesn't influence on how code works), you see the answer:

```
    var tailFeathers = 3;
    final var one = 1;
    switch (tailFeathers) {
        case one:
            System.out.print(3 + " ");
        default:
        case 44:
            System.out.print(5 + " ");
    }
```

Your `case 44` follows the `default` branch. So with `tailFeathers = 3` your program jumps to default and since there is no `break` in it executes each of following branches. That's how java's swicth-case works.

You probably want to put `default` in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Because the switch cases/branches are examined until finding a match; in your case, the match occurs in the `default` branch; once it finds a match, no more cases will be examined; but the code continues to execute until finding a `break` or to the end of the switch statement end brace if there is no `break`.

Imagine if the `default` case is the first branch, then the switch is useless; every time the `default` branch will be matched, and so it should be the last branch after any other case.

Even if you put a `break` in the `default` branch that will fix your issue of not executing the next case, `case 44`, but any next cases to the `default` branch will be unreachable and useless.

So, the fix is to keep the `default` branch at the end of the switch statement.

Comment: I don't understand how you can have a case statement inside a default statement.

Comment: No, indentation before `case 44` in your snippet doesn't mean it's inside the default branch, it's still inside the switch statement, but it is executed because there is no break in the default branch. But the optimum thing as mentioned in the answer to get the default branch as the last branch, because it matches anything else that is narrowed upfront in other cases.

Comment: @likejudo it is not a *case statement*, but a *case label* - and the Java Language Specification allows multiple labels to one statement block ( `SwitchLabel : {SwitchLabel :} BlockStatements` ) - I posted the link to the documentation in my comment 40 Minutes ago :-|

Comment: @user16320675 does that mean the default label is just another kind of case label? Furthermore that these are just like two case labels together?

Comment: @likejudo yes; see the [Grammar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-14.html#jls-SwitchLabel) for it... same section, almost same link as I included in my 2nd comment; or as text: "*... a switch label, which is either a case label or a default label.*"

Comment: @user16320675 I did not know that default is just another special type of case label and is treated similarly. I thought that default was a keyword reserved for all other values. I am surprised to find that the case matching stops even though there is a `case 44:`. So the `default` overrides the `case`?

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat of a trick question.  A *switch* block is a unique programming structure.

Firstly, the indentation they provide will throw you off.
The question implies it is the following, which *does* generate a compiler-error.

This is because the branches do not require a scope, since they are typically terminated with a *break* keyword.

```java
static void f11(){
    var tailFeathers = 3;
    final var one = 1;
    switch (tailFeathers) {
        case one: {
            System.out.print(3 + " ");
        }
        default: {
            case 44: {
                System.out.print(5 + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the *default* branch is reached, the exclusion of a *break* keyword causes it to *fall-through*.

And, since the *default* branch had been reached, the compiler does no further evaluation of any subsequent branch.

Consider the following.

```java
void example() {
    int value = 1;
    switch (value) {
        case 2:
        case 3:
        default:
        case 4: {
            System.out.println("stack");
        }
        case 5: {
            System.out.println("overflow");
        }

    }
}
```

This will print out, "stack" and "overflow".